# Autohotkeys overwrote some default windows hotkeys

Tags: command

So I threw autohotkeys on my new windows 8 machine.  It loads it's own hotkey file which changes the function of (windows button + Z).  I immediately removed the line which assigns Run Autohotkey then saved and ran that hotkey file.  Now windows key + Z does nothing instead of reverting back to the original functionality which was "open the app-specific bar of commands at the bottom of the screen."

How do I restore this default windows hotkey which autohotkey randomly decided to overwrite?

Answer (score -1):

It's been a few months, so hopefully by now, you already have your solution... I have noticed that sometimes AutoHotkey scripts get sort of stuck in place even after I rerun a new version of the script. But rebooting has always restored my hotkeys back to their original state.

Because it was not immediately clear to me how to reboot Windows 8, let me include this link to reboot instructions just in case someone needs them: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-restart-log-off-sleep-and-shutdown-windows-8/